# React useEffect rerenders with empty dependency causing infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have been trying to code in React and I came across a very strange bug. Here is my code block

```js
const [languages1, setLanguages1] = useState([])
            
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((result) => {
        let learnerLanguage = result.data
        let myLanguages = []
        for(let a = 0; a < learnerLanguage.length; a++){
            myLanguages.push({title : `${learnerLanguage.languageName}   ${learnerLanguage.level}`})
        }
        console.log(myLanguages)
        setLanguages1(myLanguages)
    });
}, [])
```

When I set my useEffect hook with a simple for loop, even though I have an empty dependency array, there is an infinite call to my server. I asked this in the Bard and it gave me this code block which works perfectly fine:

```js
const [languages1, setLanguages1] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((result) => {
        const learnerLanguage = result.data;
        const myLanguages = learnerLanguage.map((language) => ({
            title: `${language.languagename}  ${language.level}`,
            }));
        setLanguages1(myLanguages);
    });
}, []);
```

The only difference here is using **map** instead of **for loop**. Bard explains this happens because of **url** in the dependency array. **I don't understand and it is probably an AI error**

Why does my first code block work infinitely and the latter works fine?

Comment: `even though I with empty dependency array` The empty array is passed to `then`, not to `useEffect`.

Comment: You are right I made what you say. Still I have the same problem. Also I edited the question

Comment: What is `}, [])` in the end of your first code? Can you provide the complete code for it?

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better if you could provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so anyone who views this could test out your code (especially with backend code). However, I noticed something strange in your code.

Assume that `learnerLanguage` has the below type(using `TypeScript` as a demonstration):

```js
type LearnerLanguageProps = {
    // ...other properties that might not be shown,
    // in your question.
    languageName: string,
    level: string,
}[]; // basically an object array.
```

Every `title` in `languages1` should at least display `undefined undefined` as you are referring to `properties` of an `array`.

This might have triggered some unknown behaviour of `axios` as `arrays` and `objects` are **passed by references** when you assign them: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language).

Try changing it to the below code instead:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((result) => {
        let learnerLanguage = result.data;
        let myLanguages = [];
        for(let a = 0; a < learnerLanguage.length; a++){
            // find `languageName` and `title` from every `language` object,
            // in `learnerLanguage` array.
            myLanguages.push({
                title : `${learnerLanguage[a].languageName}   ${learnerLanguage[a].level}`
            });
        }
        console.log(myLanguages);
        setLanguages1(myLanguages);
    });
}, [])
```

Hope the above answer helps.